# batch will have error when use findstr in a file which is containing special character such as <

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

How to get rid from below error if my text file containing the special character like this?

```
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" {xnetwork[<11:0:-1>]}
```

If I remove this line in the text file, then my batch program can run smoothly, else it will give the below error:

```
The filename, directory, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I understand that it is cause by the special such as < in the file, but i am not able to remove this in a file, i just wanna batch program to ignore this...

Below is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET matchpattern="0632"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (log_network.txt) DO (SET currentline=%%a & CALL :match_function)
pause

GOTO :EOF
:match_function
    ECHO %currentline%|findstr /I /R /C:"%matchpattern%" > NUL
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo %currentline%
    )
```

log_network.txt:

```
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.5846"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.7425"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.1420"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.0632"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.1112"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.8524"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3675"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3344"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.1276"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.4796"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3349"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.0048"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" {xnetwork[<11:0:-1>]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `%%a` variable have to be between `"` to escape the `<` and `>` chars.

Try like this :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET matchpattern="0632"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (log_network.txt) DO CALL :match_function "%%a"
pause
GOTO :EOF

:match_function
ECHO %1 | findstr /I /R /C:"%matchpattern%" > NUL && echo %~1
```

Comment: May i know why %%a is not equal to "%%a"?
without following what you modified in the match function but only add the double quote for the %%a, i'm able to get rid from error easily...Thanks...but instead of blindly follow, i hope to know why i need to put ""?

Comment: If you don't put `%%a` between `"` the `<`and `>` char will be interpreted as redirection char. That's why you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to enclose in quotes the data that you are echoing

```
    echo("%currentline%"|findstr /I /R /C:"%matchpattern%" > NUL
```

but then the quotes will be included in the data feed to findstr and you may have to take them into account. And if the lines start or contains multiple quotes it can also give errors as the problematic characters can fall out of the quotes.

You can use an argument to the subroutine

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (log_network.txt) DO (CALL :match_function "%%a")
....
:match_function
    echo(%1|findstr /I /R /C:"%matchpattern%" > NUL
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo(%~1
    )
    goto :eof
```

but you also have to consider the aditional quotes

To avoid it, you can use delayed expansion, but it is complicated

```
 @ECHO OFF
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    SET "matchpattern=0632"

    FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (log_network.txt) DO (SET "currentline=%%a" & CALL :match_function)
    pause

    GOTO :EOF

:match_function
    (cmd /q /v:on /c "echo(!currentline!")|findstr /I /R /C:"%matchpattern%" > NUL
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo(%currentline%
    )
    goto :eof
```

To echo the special characters to the pipe using a variable name you need delayed expansion, but inside a pipe, as a new process is created for each of the sides of the pipe, you can not ensure the `cmd` instance that will execute the `echo` has or not delayed expansion enabled, so, it is necessary to directy spawn the instance with delayed expansion enabled, then from there echo the variable and then the data is piped into `findstr`

This is easier and usually a lot faster

```
@ECHO OFF
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    SET "matchpattern=0632"

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        'findstr /r /i /c:"%matchpattern%" log_network.txt'
    ) do (
        echo(%%a
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "matchpattern=0632"
findstr /I /R /C:"%matchpattern%" log_network.txt
```

However, in this case you don't need a Batch file, just enter this in the command-line:

```
findstr "0632" log_network.txt
```

The /I switch is not needed because you are not searching letters, the /R switch is not needed because you look just for the "0632" literal, and the /C switch is not needed because you look just for one string (the only one).